# How to remove an item from the list widget using a button on kivymd

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm having a problem on how can I remove an item from the list widget using a button and possibly how can I clear the widget after checking all the item.

py.file

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def add_item(self):
        global lst
        i = 0
        if self.ids.inp.text == "":
            close_button = MDFlatButton(text="Okay", on_release=self.close_dialog)
            self.dialog = MDDialog(title="Invalid", text="No item added",
                                   size_hint=(0.7, 1), buttons=[close_button])
            self.dialog.open()
        else:
            list_items.append(self.ids.inp.text)
            self.ids.inp.text = ''
            for x in range(len(list_items)):
                lst = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text=list_items[i])
                i += 1
            self.ids.list.add_widget(lst)

    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def remove_item(self):
        pass
```

Example image:
[image]

Comment: Providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) increases the chances of you getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For removing the item that is selected you can use `self.ids.list.children` to access all the items in your list and simply use `remove_widget()` to remove that item.And to clear your list after all the items are selected,you can use `clear_widgets()`.